# How to disable website for older browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser

I'm using HTML5, CSS3, and other new technologies.

I want to prevent my users from using old browsers in a standard way.

- How to detect old browsers in javascript or PHP?
- How to show alert users properly?

Comment: Take a look at http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Don't block users from viewing your page. Just give them a polite reminder their browser is ancient, or maybe even provide update links for the browser they're using.

Comment: Websites should be browser agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website provides a easy to use script that helps your users in a nice way to upgrade their browsers:

http://www.browser-update.org/

> 1. Include our small javascript notification on your website
> 2. Visitors with out-dated browser will be informed by a little, undisturbing bar, that his browser is not up-to-date and it is
>      recommended to update.
> 3. By clicking the bar, he will get to an info page with arguments why to change/update and some browser choices.
> 4. If the visitor ignores the advice, it won't appear again for some time.

It won't prevent the users from using your website, it will just notify them that they have an outdated browser and try to encourage them to update, and it does so in a discreet way.

By default, the script will give this message for a recommended set of old browsers (that automatically gets updated over time when browsers become too old), but you can also manually choose for which browsers the message will appear.

You're also able to customize the looks of the message.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind when I made that comment on the question :D +1.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than diminishing peoples browsing experience by blocking them, consider progressive enhancement instead. While it may take a little more work it will be worth it. And as already suggested take a look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com)